# Visual Studio - ERROR when importing controls from a DLL

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am trying to import custom controls (in the toolbox) into visual studio (namely Service Manager Authoring Tools for those who are familiar).

I click "Choose Items" in the toolbox to add the custom controls. They are WPF tools, so I click on WPF and browse to the assemblies (located within the installation folder for the Service Manager Authoring Tool) and open them, it successfully loads the list of controls and I can choose which ones I want (for example listpicker). However when I click close it gives me a notification:

**“The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer”**

and proceeds to list a number of controls including listpicker. Thereby not allowing me to use it from the toolbox.

The .NET framework version of the project I am working on is 3.5, so I am assuming it is loading a 4.0 version of the tool hence not allowing me to use it. However, this doesn't make sense because the Authoring Tool also uses framework 3.5, and I am able to use the tool within it.

Do I have to find a 3.5 version of the assembly or is there a way to configure Visual Studio to accept the tool? If any information is required from me please tell me and I will provide. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The three .dll's are:

```
Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Controls.dll
Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ExtendedControls.dll
Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SMControls.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I opened up this issue to Microsoft Engineers and they are working on a fix. For other users who are having this problem, here is the page setup for this issue: Once a solution is reached I will try to post it here as well.

[Visual Studio Bug ID# 905629, Dedicated Page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/905629/visual-studio-error-when-importing-controls-from-a-dll)